# SSIS WebServiceTask all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached

Tags: sql-server, soap, ssis

I found an error on my SSIS in a "Web Service Task".

I set a http connection to connect to a soap web service and then use a "Web Service Task" to execute a web method for get data into SQL DATABASE.
I use a "for loop" and variables for looping to get data every months in year or every products in every month in 8 years.

Sometimes, the SSIS can execute and process completed but sometimes, the process stop due to error about a max pool size.

I don't know where can I set a max pool size?

> "Error: 0xC002F304 at Web Service Task, Web Service Task: An error
>   occurred with the following error message:
>   "Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.WebServiceTask.WebserviceTaskException:
>   The Web Service threw an error during method execution. The error is:
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to
>   process request. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Timeout
>   expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection
>   from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections
>   were in use and max pool size was reached.    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()"

[image]

Comment: This looks to be an issue with the web service rather than SSIS. Although you could simply specify a larger pools size in the web service database connection string, that would only mask the problem. Make sure the web service code uses an open-late-close-early pattern and/or `using` block to make sure connections are properly disposed.

Comment: I found the error occurs at "web service task" when it call and getting xml from the soap. it means that is due to web service issue not destination database right?

Comment: Right, the SqlException during the web service call occurs in the web service. You might be able to work-around the problem temporarily by changing the connection string in the web service (not SSIS), as @kalaolani suggested. The root cause might be that the web service isn't managing connections properly or there are too many concurrent queries due to reasons not apparent from the information in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Add Max Pool Size=X to the connection string.

Comment: That will only mask the problem, The default is 100 concurrent connections (active queries), which is quite a lot.

Comment: It's a quick fix that can be used while the issue is investigated. Masking the problem so that you can get more information to analyze the problem is the first step I would think.

Comment: you mean a connection string for SQL database right?

I already set it to the connection string
"Data Source=WIN-ET85CTFLDSV;Initial Catalog=WebServices;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;Max Pool Size=1000;"
but still found the error.

Comment: Take a look at this... kind of done following this after Mr. Big Rep's flame.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx